# Can we rename the [scala-meta] tag into [scalameta]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I'm one of the maintainers of the Scalameta project and the correct name is Scalameta without hyphens. Is it possible to rename the [scala-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-meta) tag into [scalameta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scalameta)?

Comment: This is the site, right: https://scalameta.org ?

Comment: yep, that's it.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao for taking care of this so quickly!

Comment: No worries. It wasn't hard to figure out the project name from your GitHub profile, which made my work easier.